# Prolog How to skip a fact

Tags: prolog, backtracking

As the title says how can I accomplish this?
I have this knowledge base

```
person(alice).
person(mark).
person(sally).

likes(alice,coke).
likes(alice,fanta).
likes(alice,sprite).
likes(mark,water).
likes(mark,coffee).
likes(sally,pepsi).
```

And I want to output every drink that alice likes that is not fanta.Can someone explain how to achieve it and why it's done that way?

Comment: Pretty straightforward. `likes(alice, Drink), Drink \= fanta.` It just says, "Alice likes Drink, and Drink isn't fanta".

Answer (score 1):

If you input the query `likes(alice, X)` you get all drinks that alice likes including fanta:

```
?- likes(alice, X).
X = coke ;
X = fanta ;
X = sprite.
```

If you add the goal `X \= fanta` in conjunction to that (note: must come after), then when `X` is bound to `fanta`, it will fail the goal `X \= fanta`, and it will backtrack to find other choices:

```
?- likes(alice, X), X \= fanta.
X = coke ;
X = sprite.
```

(note: pressing `;` to get the next choice)

Suggested reading: [Proof search](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse6)

Comment: Thank you!And I did try a similar one like X =\= fanta and it didn't work.But why?

Comment: [`=\=`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate==\=/2) is numeric inequality. [`\=`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=\=/2) is a failing unification test (negation of [`=`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D)/2)).

Comment: @jakHunter check the Prolog documentation. It explains what all the operators are. There's also `\==` which is not the same thing as `\=` or `=\=`.